# How to find perimeter of image in Android?

Tags: java, android

I am doing an Android project. I have an image in imageView. I have done the coding and formula to find the perimeter of image and then convert the pixel unit to inch, but I am not sure if it is right or not.

I have tested the finding of perimeter and then unit conversion in one particular image. I have used this particular formula for conversion in Java.

```
ImageView imageView = findViewById(R.id.your_image_view_id);
Drawable drawable = imageView.getDrawable();
int width = drawable.getIntrinsicWidth();
int height = drawable.getIntrinsicHeight();
int perimeter = 2 * (width + height);

float pixelsPerInch = getResources().getDisplayMetrics().densityDpi;
float inches = perimeter / pixelsPerInch;
```

This above code for finding the perimeter of image and then converting the pixel unit to inch unit.

Suppose the width of the image is 678. The height of the image is 452. The logical DPI of the running OS is 440. I am getting perimeter  = 5.14 inch. Can anyone confirm me that I am using right formula and right method because there is no way to confirm this?

Comment: It seems correct. Why do you use `getIntrinsicWidth` and `getIntrinsicHeight` instead of `getWidth` and `getHeight`?